# Python Spotify API How to pass variable into the input prompt from the util.prompt_for_user_token response

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am working to create a pipeline with the spotify API that logs my streaming history. I am planning to automate it by uploading it as a lambda function and scheduling it to run every few hours. I have everything mostly in order, except for that on the first run the API requires web authentication. Here is my code:

```
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
import urllib3

un = USERNAME
scope = 'user-read-recently-played'
cid = CLIENT_ID
csid = CLIENT_SECRET_ID
redr = r'http://localhost:8888/callback/'

token = util.prompt_for_user_token(un,scope,cid,csid,redr)
```

When this is run for the first time, this message pops up:

```
User authentication requires interaction with your
            web browser. Once you enter your credentials and
            give authorization, you will be redirected to
            a url.  Paste that url you were directed to to
            complete the authorization.


Opened <LINK HERE> in your browser


Enter the URL you were redirected to:
```

And then I have to copy the link from my browser into that space. I can get the URL that I need to paste using urllib3:

```
req_adr = ADDRESS_IT_OPENS_IN_BROWSER
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
resp = http.request('GET',req_adr)
redrurl = resp.geturl()
```

But I don't know how to pass it into the input prompt from the util.prompt_for_user_token response

Any suggestions would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out there is a workaround. You can run it one time on a local machine and that generates a a file called .cache-USERNAME. If you include that file in your deployment package you don't have to copy/paste the URL and it is able to be automated with a lambda function in AWS.